# Exception "remote object implements illegal remote interface"?

Tags: java, rmi

I use rmi in Java. however there is a ExportException "remote object implements illegal remote interface".

Here is my code， May someone help me?

```
public interface RemotePeer extends Remote {

    public abstract void displayInf(String inf);

    public abstract void exit();

    public abstract boolean isActive();
}


 public class Peer implements RemotePeer{
        public Peer(){}
        ....

        public static void main(String[] args) {
           Peer p=new Peer()
           RemotePeer remoteP=(RemotePeer) UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(p, 0);
           Registry registry = LocateRegistry.getRegistry();
           }
}
```

Comment: Have you tried using UnicastRemoteObject?

Comment: @Abu Why? What difference would that make?

Answer (score 45, accepted):

Every method in a `Remote` interface must be able to throw a `RemoteException`. Your interface should be:

```
public interface RemotePeer extends Remote {

    public abstract void displayInf(String inf) throws RemoteException;

    public abstract void exit() throws RemoteException;

    public abstract boolean isActive() throws RemoteException;
}
```

You might want to take a look at the [RMI Tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/rmi/overview.html).